# S3 redirect 302 object with s3cmd

Tags: python, amazon-s3, s3cmd

I wish to create redirect object.

It is redirect to JSON file. HTML expires header will not work for me.

```
touch google
s3cmd --add-header='Location: http://www.google.com/' -P put google s3://bucket/google
```

It does not work as I do not set HTTP sttaus to `302`

I prefer `s3cmd` as it is already installed on target server but python might ok as well if `s3cmd` can't do that.

Answer (score 5):

You should set **x-amz-website-redirect-location** header when putting object and access it via **region specific website endpoint** to archive this. See the document here:  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/how-to-page-redirect.html

Comment: Thanks. But I actually saw that article. I do not understand how to do that with s3cmd if even possible.

Comment: Try --add-header=x-amz-website-redirect-location:VALUE